# Kubectl dnsutils fails

Tags: kubernetes

I am debugging DNS using [dnsutils](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/)

I have created a dnsutils pod and I can see it running

```
$ kubectl get pods dnsutils -n infrastructure
NAME       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
dnsutils   1/1       Running   43         1d
```

When I run nslookup I am getting

```
kubectl -n infrastructure exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default


;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

If I extract `/etc/resolv.conf` I can see

```
kubectl -n infrastructure exec -ti dnsutils -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 100.64.0.10
search infrastructure.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local eu-west-1.compute.internal
options ndots:5
```

Any help how I can debug this further?

Comment: What cloud provider are you using?

Comment: @DanielMarques AWS is my cloud providers. It seems like I am having a problem with kube-dns pod, which works for a while (random amount of time) and then just stops working (when dnsutils also is not working)

Comment: can you paste the `kubectl describe` and `kubectl logs` from the core-dns container? Also, how did you create your kubernetes cluster?

Comment: @DanielMarques I have these pods
```
kube-dns-6b4f4b544c-f8t4m                                              3/3       Running   0          19m
kube-dns-6b4f4b544c-gbnc6                                              3/3       Running   0          19m
kube-dns-autoscaler-6b658bd4d5-84nk4 
```
https://justpaste.it/97mep

https://justpaste.it/91grw

Comment: I have a working cluster on AWS within a EC2 instance and my core-dns config is very different from yours. Did you use kubeadm tool to create your cluster?

Comment: I inherited this configuration unfortunately. They used KOPS to create cluster.

Comment: hmm, it looks like kops it has a different way to handle with dns. Maybe you can find some info here https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/getting_started/aws/#configure-dns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out that I had some `calico-node` pods in `Running` state, but `1/2`, which I haven't noticed before. I had to kill these pods and also `calico-kube-controllers` several times, before they were recreated successfully. Then I killed `kube-dns` pods and everything is working now.